# Grails and datasource usage

Tags: grails, service, controller, datasource

Friends:

In the service class I am trying to query the DB and get result to populate my domain class.  I am not sure if I thinking this correctly or I have to use the find methods approach to fill my domain classes ?

The understanding I have is:
Grails thru URLMappings will call my controller and inside that I can do a direct instantiation of Service class.

I am then using SQL directly there inside Service class to iterate thru the Resultset and populate the Domain class list and return that to controller class which will then return a list back to the REST call user.

Is this the right approach or I have to call Service from controller but using the find method and that will fill the list and that should be used to return the list ?

In all cases I am using the H2 db itself.

Regards and Thank you for your time.
-Narahari

Comment: Try working through some of the sample apps here http://guides.grails.org/#/index

Answer (score 0):

**As per the standards, Flow goes from controller > Service > DAO.**

All the business logic should be written in the service class only. 
As you are using DAO layer is hidden through GORM.
Grails is very powerful and productive language. You use GORM for database activity. For your scenario, you could use findAll, createCriteria, HQL or native SQL query approach, but the flow should not be broken. It means that if write database related code in the controller then in future it will be difficult to maintain debug code.